# ISNULL returns 0 for a hardcoded column with NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why this statement return 0 instead of empty string? I am actually using a view which select statement containg hardcoded column return NULL. While I am trying to check if its a NULL, it actually returns 0.

```
SELECT ISNULL((SELECT NULL as Col), '')
```

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated...

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Vex.png)

Comment: New to mySQL.  I had the same issue with:

`ifnull(fname, '') + '  ' + ifnull(lname, '') Name`

I used:

`concat(ifnull(fname, ''), ' ', ifnull(lname, '')) Name`

and it worked, in case anyone else ran into the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NULL` does not have a clear type, but in a plain `SELECT NULL`, it gets returned as type `int`. When you have an expression involving an `int` and a `char(N)`, `int` wins, the `char(N)` value gets converted to `int`, not the other way around. To make things more confusing, `''` happens to be convertible to `int` without any problem, and the result of the conversion is `0`.

`SELECT ISNULL((SELECT CAST(NULL AS char(1)) AS col), '')` should return an empty string.

Comment: thanks when we run plain `SELECT NULL` why it's return `NULL`

Comment: @tinka What else would you expect it to return?

Comment: i have confusion when we run `SELECT ISNULL((SELECT NULL), '')` it return `0` then same inside query when we run separately `SELECT NULL`  it return `NULL`

Comment: @tinka Er... yes. In both cases, `SELECT NULL` is returning `NULL`. Read my answer again: the value `0` isn't coming from the `(SELECT NULL)` expression, it's coming from the `''` expression. The effect the `(SELECT NULL)` expression has is to get `''` converted to a different type.