# SQL Server:Case Expression returning 0 instead of empty string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below is the query which returns 0 when not using convert to varchar. It compares integer value

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
       WHEN Duration IS NULL
          THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, '') 
          ELSE Duration 
    END AS Duration  
FROM
    Contribution 
WHERE 
    CreatedBy = @in_userID  AND ContentStatus = @ContentStatus   

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    *,
    CASE 
       WHEN Duration IS NULL
          THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR, '')  
          ELSE Duration 
    END AS Duration  
FROM
    Training  
WHERE 
    CreatedBy = @in_userID  AND ContentStatusValue = @TrainingStatus
```

On using union all, without using convert the case returns 0 instead ''. When using convert the problem is resolved.

Can anyone say why this happens?

Comment: Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165587/isnull-returns-0-for-a-hardcoded-column-with-null-value

Comment: What is the datatype for Duration ?

Comment: it is of varchar datatype

Comment: How about IsNull(duration,'')  rather than the case

Comment: It is also returning 0 only

Comment: I dont think the problem is with case or isnull. It is with using case  along with union

Comment: Are both Training and Contribution varchar or is one an numeric ?

Comment: Its because your Duration in Traning table is INT and not varchar - You can get arround it with just casting your last else to else cast(duration as varchar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your `Duration` has `INT` type, so you can do conversation :

```
SELECT c.col1, c.col2, ISNULL(CAST(c.Duration AS VARCHAR(255)),'') Duration  
FROM Contribution c
WHERE c.CreatedBy = @in_userID  AND
      c.ContentStatus = @ContentStatus 
UNION ALL
SELECT t.col1, t.col2, ISNULL(CAST(t.Duration AS VARCHAR(255), '') 
FROM Training t 
WHERE t.CreatedBy = @in_userID AND
      t.ContentStatusValue = @TrainingStatus;
```

Comment: are you sure that is varchar in both tables? Im quite sure that's not the case :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `COALESCE`

```
SELECT *,COALESCE(convert( varchar(255),Duration ),'') 
AS Duration  FROM Contribution WHERE CreatedBy = @in_userID 
and ContentStatus = @ContentStatus   
UNION ALL

SELECT *,COALESCE(convert( varchar(255),Duration ),'') AS Duration 
FROM Training  WHERE CreatedBy = @in_userID  
and   ContentStatusValue=@TrainingStatus.
```